# Resize pictures

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I'm using VBA code to decrease the images in my document to fit the printable page width:

```
Dim myPageWidthWithoutMargins As Single
myPageWidthWithoutMargins = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PageWidth - ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin - ActiveDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin

Dim myShape As InlineShape
For Each myShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
   myShape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   If myShape.Width > myPageWidthWithoutMargins Then
      myShape.Width = myPageWidthWithoutMargins
   End If
Next
```

It does not work as a part of another sub, but it does work as a separate macro I launch manually after all other operations from the sub have been done. Why and how to fix that?

===============

It's a part of a big sub that converts an HTML file into the corresponding Word document. Here is the code used before to work with images:

```
Dim myImgStyle As Word.Style
Set myImgStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add("CenteredImageStyle", wdStyleTypeParagraph)
With myImgStyle
    .BaseStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles(cNormalStyleName)
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End With

Dim myShape As InlineShape
For Each myShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If Not myShape.LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
       myShape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
       myShape.LinkFormat.BreakLink
       myShape.Range.Select
       Dim myParaRange As Range
       Set myParaRange = Selection.Paragraphs.First.Range
       If Selection.Start = myParaRange.Start And Selection.End = myParaRange.End - 1 Then
           Selection.Style = myImgStyle
       End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: At the time you execute this code in your other subroutine, are your images InlineShapes or Shapes ?

Comment: @grahamj42, we are using our VBA macros to convert and format the source HTML file into a Word document of a special format. All our shapes are 'inline shapes'. I have just added the only code we use to work with images before the problem code to the original post.